# What is causing my CMake Multiple target pattern error?

Tags: makefile, cmake, box2d

I have been trying to install box2D 2.3 on codeblocks. All was going smoothly until I hit a roadblock with the .make files. I believe most of the problems were caused by Codeblocks using "\" instead of "/" for filepaths. However, I am stuck as I am getting the error:

```
||=== Build: all in Box2D (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
Box2D\CMakeFiles\Box2D.dir\build.make|803|*** multiple target patterns.  Stop.|
CMakeFiles\Makefile2|96|recipe for target 'Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/all' failed|
C:\Users\111\Documents\C++ Libraries\box2d-2.3.0\box2d-2.3.0\Box2D\Build\Makefile|82|recipe for target 'all' failed|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Line 803:

```
@$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --green --bold --progress-dir="C:/Users/151/Documents/C++ Libraries/box2d-2.3.0/box2d-2.3.0/Box2D/Build/CMakeFiles" --progress-num=$(CMAKE_PROGRESS_47) "Linking CXX static library libBox2D.a"
```

This is the chunk of relevant code that could be causing the error in the .make file.

```
# External object files for target Box2D
Box2D_EXTERNAL_OBJECTS = \
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/Joints/b2DistanceJoint.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/Joints/b2FrictionJoint.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/Joints/b2GearJoint.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/Joints/b2Joint.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/Joints/b2MotorJoint.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/Joints/b2MouseJoint.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/Joints/b2PrismaticJoint.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/Joints/b2PulleyJoint.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/Joints/b2RevoluteJoint.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/Joints/b2RopeJoint.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/Joints/b2WeldJoint.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/Joints/b2WheelJoint.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/Contacts/b2CircleContact.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/Contacts/b2Contact.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/Contacts/b2ContactSolver.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/Contacts/b2PolygonAndCircleContact.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/Contacts/b2EdgeAndCircleContact.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/Contacts/b2EdgeAndPolygonContact.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/Contacts/b2ChainAndCircleContact.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/Contacts/b2ChainAndPolygonContact.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/Contacts/b2PolygonContact.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/b2Body.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/b2ContactManager.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/b2Fixture.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/b2Island.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/b2World.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Dynamics/b2WorldCallbacks.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Common/b2BlockAllocator.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Common/b2Draw.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Common/b2Math.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Common/b2Settings.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Common/b2StackAllocator.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Common/b2Timer.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Collision/Shapes/b2CircleShape.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Collision/Shapes/b2EdgeShape.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Collision/Shapes/b2ChainShape.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Collision/Shapes/b2PolygonShape.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Collision/b2BroadPhase.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Collision/b2CollideCircle.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Collision/b2CollideEdge.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Collision/b2CollidePolygon.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Collision/b2Collision.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Collision/b2Distance.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Collision/b2DynamicTree.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Collision/b2TimeOfImpact.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/Rope/b2Rope.cpp.obj
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/build.make
Box2D/libBox2D.a: Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/link.txt

    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --green --bold --progress-dir="C:/Users/111/Documents/C++ Libraries/box2d-2.3.0/box2d-2.3.0/Box2D/Build/CMakeFiles" --progress-num=$(CMAKE_PROGRESS_47) "Linking CXX static library libBox2D.a"
    cd /d C:/Users/111/DOCUME~1/C__LIB~1/BOX2D-~1.0/BOX2D-~1.0/Box2D/Build/Box2D && $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -P CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/cmake_clean_target.cmake
    cd /d C:/Users/111/DOCUME~1/C__LIB~1/BOX2D-~1.0/BOX2D-~1.0/Box2D/Build/Box2D && $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/link.txt --verbose=$(VERBOSE)

# Rule to build all files generated by this target.
Box2D/CMakeFiles/Box2D.dir/build: Box2D/libBox2D.a
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any backslashes in your sample makefiles so I don't think that's the problem.

Make cannot deal with pathnames containing whitespace.  You appear to have a directory named `C:/Users/151/Documents/C++ Libraries`.  That cannot work with makefiles.  Rename the directory `C++ Libraries` to something like `C++Libraries` (no spaces) and it will probably work.

Otherwise, choose a different generator from makefiles.